# WebApi2 RoutePrefix and endpoint Route = Not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have decorated my api controller such as:

`[RoutePrefix("api/admin/notification")]
 public class LanguageController : BaseController`

Inside, I have this GET endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("app/{productGuid}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllNotificationsForApp([FromUri]string productGuid)
```

Now, I am assuming the correct way of accessing this resource is:

`GET http://[api-url]/api/admin/notification/app/someguid`

However, this yields a 404.

What I have tried:

-Removing `[FromUri]`

-Passing productGuid as part of querystring, i.e `.../app?productGuid=something` (as opposed to `/app/{productGuid}`)

Yes, I am using `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` and I've verified other api controllers that also use RoutePrefix to be working.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `[FromUri]` is used to force Web API to read a complex type from the URI. Removing it should have worked. You could also look into changing the parameter from `string` to `Guid` and applying a proper constraint to the placeholder in the route. ie: `[Route("app/{productGuid:guid}")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't have two api controllers with the same class name, even if they are mapped to different routes.

I had another controller named `LanguageController`, in a different namespace and mapped to a different route; I had to rename one of them to make it work.

Based on [Different RoutePrefix, same controller name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627433/different-routeprefix-same-controller-name)

Answer (score 1):

`[FromUri]` is used to force Web API to read a complex type from the URI. Removing it should have worked.

You could also look into changing the parameter from `string` to `Guid` and applying a proper constraint to the placeholder in the route. ie: `[Route("app/{productGuid:guid}")]`

```
[RoutePrefix("api/admin/notification")]
public class LanguageController : BaseController {
    //GET: api/admin/notification/app/{guid}
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("app/{productGuid:guid}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllNotificationsForApp(Guid productGuid) {...}

}
```

Other things to check:

Make sure that `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` is done before your convention-based routes. The order is important as first match wins.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have pointed out the cause of my problem.

Comment: @Carlitrosss, yep. that happens sometimes. glad you were able to eventaully figure out the problem. Happy coding!!!